# Kubernetes can't start due to too many open files in system

Tags: linux, docker, containers, kubernetes, devops

I am trying create a bunch of pods, services and deployment using Kubernetes, but keep hitting the following errors when I run the `kubectl describe` command.

`for "POD" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot start container bbdb58770a848733bf7130b1b230d809fcec3062b2b16748c5e4a8b12cc0533a: [8] System error: too many open files in system\n"`

I have already terminated all pods and try restarting the machine, but it doesn't solve the issue. I am not an Linux expert, so I am just wondering how shall find all the open files and close them?

Comment: Hi Bob, there is an github [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13385#issuecomment-138576499) reporting the same problem. Probably you'll get help if you comment there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can confirm which process is hogging file descriptors by running:

```
lsof | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

That will give you a sorted list of open FD counts with the pid of the process. Then you can look up each process w/

```
ps -p <pid>
```

If the main hogs are docker/kubernetes, then I would recommend following along on the [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13385#issuecomment-138576499) that caesarxuchao referenced.

Comment: Okay thanks! Let me accept the answer first before trying it out. The solution seems pretty straight forward. :)